# How do you convey that something is said slowly in written dialogue?

Tags: dialogue

I am writing a dialogue and I want a word to be said slowly so it is clarified.

The dialogue goes like this

"What's this?"

"It's a Bellis perennis."

"What?"

"Bellis perennis." (I want this to be said slowly)

Should I separate the letters with dashed like this

"B-e-l-l-i-s p-e-r-e-n-n-i-s."

or should I insert spaces between the letters. But I don't want the reader to think I said each letter on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting dashes between letters, which suggests that each letter is pronounced individually, you could put dashes between the syllables.

> Bell-is-per-enn-is

Comment: What dashes? These are hyphens, not dashes.

Comment: I meant hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

The convention for indicating that the speaker is sounding out a word slowly, emphasizing the accented syllables, is to put pauses between syllables. That can be done typographically like this:

*BEL...lis...per...EN...nis*

Putting a dash between all the letters suggests that the word is being spelled out, not sounded out.

Comment: Can you find me a reference for this convention because I want to read about it more. What's wrong with Matts suggestion to separate the syllables with dashes? Thanks!

Comment: Matt's idea is OK. It suggests the speaker is emphatically marking the syllable boundaries, though not necessarily doing so very slowly. Depends on what you what.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Answer (score -1):

> B-e-l-l-i-s p-e-r-e-n-n-i-s.

This would indicate to me that each letter is pronounced individually.

To indicate something is said slowly, I would just add extra letters:

> Beeeeeellissssss pereeeeeeeennisssssss

Comment: This might work for familiar words with long vowel sounds, like "Helloooooooo", but in this case the extra letters make it look like it should be pronounced differently than the original.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but do you have any reference/research that can support your answer?